# How to get a value of a Javascript object from another javascript object in the same array of objects?

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects

How do you get the value of a javascript object from another javascript object in the same array of objects and use it to calculate it's value?  See below example:

```
//I'm trying to calculate **revenue x spend_pct** and store it in the **value of the third object** below.  

const a=[
  {parameter: "revenue", value: 1000000000},
  {parameter: "spend_pct", value: 0.25},
  {parameter: "addressable_spend", value: ????}
]
```

from the OUTSIDE of the array, i would normally do something like:
const x = a.filter(p=>p.parameter==="revenue")[0].value*a.filter(p=>p.parameter==="spend_pct")[0].value

Is there a way to do this from INSIDE the array object itself and assign this to the value of the third object? I would like to do this as an initial state in Redux and have the state update each time a change is made to either revenue or spend pct in my app.

Thanks